# Domain transfer: is my transfer incomplete, or is propagation taking a while?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dns-zone, domain-registrar, domain-registration

I transferred a domain between registrars (from AWS to a local one). Route 53’s logs show the transfer as complete. My new registrar and https://dnc.org.nz/whois/whois-lookup/ (it’s a .co.nz domain) both show the transferred domain as ‘Active’. Does this mean the transfer has completed?

I also switched nameservers to the new registrar. When I use a tool like https://dnschecker.org/ to check the NS records for the domain, I see they haven’t propagated. When I `dig` my new registrar’s name servers, I see the updated NS records (and all my other records).

Should I just wait? Could this be the domain transfer taking a while, or is it just DNS propagation? So far, it’s been around 12 hours since I started the transfer.

The TTL on all my records was and is 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain transfers usually takes 5-7 days in ([www.domain.com/domains/transfer](http://www.domain.com/domains/transfer)) depending on the previous and current domain provider. This is due to several variables that has to be considered including the cooperation of the prior domain registrar, and making sure that the domain is unlocked with the correct authorization code.

Name Servers on the other hand takes [48-72 hours to propagate](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/update-name-servers). DNS changes usually takes a few hours but it can take up to 72 hours for the changes to fully propagate across the internet.

It will only be a matter of time until the transfer and propagation completes their respective processes. You'll just need to wait it out for now.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd overlooked in the WHOIS was the `domain_delegaterequested` field. It was set to `no` for my domain, as it had been suspended by my previous registrar.

The values for this field can be:

> yes or no, depending on whether the domain is marked for export into the DNS zone as a delegation. If no, then the domain will not appear in the DNS even if all other information (for example, suitable nameservers) is present to otherwise allow it to do so. If set to yes, then the domain will appear in the DNS providing the other criteria are satisfied.

(https://docs.internetnz.nz/whois/)

I contacted my new registrar and they were able to set this field to `yes`. The change took an hour or two. After that, my records began to propagate.